# load images incrementally in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How do you load images incrementally on click, as opposed to loading an array of images in one go in Rails?

I have a gallery that could contain many many images. I want to show these on an index page but obviously I dont want to load them all at once. How do I load more items to the gallery as the user clicks through?

```
.fotorama
  - entries.each do |photo|
    = link_to (image_tag photo.attachment.url), entry_path(photo)
```

I am currently using this through a fotorama gallery plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify data attribute to you link with image url and, on click, preload image and add image src to image tag.

```
$('a').click (e)->
  e.preventDefault()
  src = $this.data('image')
  img = new Image()
  img.src = src
  img.onload = ->
    $this.find('img').attr('src', src)
```